# Why can friend class have access to Base class private data through Derived class

Tags: c++, friend

This is my first time to post a question here.

```
class Base {
     private:
         int base;
     friend class Question;
};

class Derived : public Base{
    private:
        int super;
};

class Question{
    public:
        void test(Base& base, Derived & derived)
        {
           int value1 =base.base;  // No problem, because Question is a friend class of base
           int value2 =derived.super; // Compile error, because Question is not a friend class of base
           // Question is here
           int value3 =derived.base;  // No Compile error here, but I do not understand why.
        } 
};
```

The question is indicated in the last row of Class Question.

Comment: `No Compile error here, but I do not understand why`: That's the purpose of making a friend in the first place, that's to share your toys with him.

Comment: This works because the member still belongs to the base class, even if the instance happens to be a derived value. In general, this is how static type checking works -- you can pass your derived object to a function that accepts the base by reference, and type checking in that function is done as if it were a base instance, because the actual type isn't usually known until runtime.

Answer (score 2):

`friend` applies to all of the members of that type, whether or not the type is inherited.  To stress this point: it is the *members* that are shared.

This means that your `Question` class has access to all members of `Base`, which is just `int Base::base`.  Whether it accesses this member through an instance of `Derived` is irrelevant, because the actual member being accessed was declared on `Base`.